# "OpenGL ES Driver" Instrument not showing any data

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, instruments

I'm using Instruments to try and optimise my OpenGL usage on IOS.
In the past, when I have used it, both the "OpenGL ES Analyzer" and "OpenGL ES Driver" instruments captured data.

However at the moment, the "OpenGL ES Analyzer" captures data fine, but the "OpenGL ES Driver" instruments contains no data whatsoever. I've tried resetting the MAC and the IOS device, but still no data is captured.

Is there a secret setting I may have switched on that would break this?

The device is a iPhone 4.

I've added a screenshot below to show what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: If you click the little inspector button next to the OpenGL ES Driver instrument, then click the "Configure" button, it should show you a list of statistics it can track. You could try turning on a few of those and see if it kicks the main Tiler and Renderer stats back into working. You could also try running the OpenGL ES Driver instrument by itself, without the Analyzer going at the same time.

Comment: Ah, it seemed all the traces were turned off in that configuration section (which is quite well hidden!). Thanks!